# Simple applications of group theory which can be understood by a senior undergrad

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, group-theory

I am looking for references (books or web links) which have "simple" examples on the use of group theory in physics or science in general.

I have looked at many books on the subject unfortunately they usually require extensive technical coverage of the basics, i.e. the 1st 100 pages or something, to be able to start discussing applications.

I believe that there is an easy way to explain anything (it's just hard to find it).

Comment: Read this post http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=1478&page=1

Comment: Well there is very good series of video lectures available ........
Check this for group theory.
http://www.asti.ac.za/lectures.php

Comment: Well, to see "examples" of group theory in physics, you first need to know the language, i.e. "group theory".  And without "extensive technical coverage of the basics", which really means "coverage of the basics", then you will NOT really understand the examples.

Answer (score 2):

My two favorites for group theory in physics are:

1. [Lie Groups for Pedestrians](http://www.powells.com/biblio?isbn=978-0486421858)
   for a general introduction to Lie groups, mostly in a particle physics context.
2. [Levine's Quantum Chemistry](http://www.powells.com/biblio?isbn=9780136131069), for an introduction to group theory in molecules.

Comment: I second the vote for Lie Groups for Pedestrians. It's an excellent introduction.  (I haven't read the other).

Answer (score 1):

I  recommend " The  Theory  of Groups  and  Quantum  Mechanics " by  Hermann  Weyl http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jQbEcDDqGb8C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Although  the  book  is  written  in  a  old  school  way, I found  it  interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Posted the same thing on [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/comprehensive-book-on-group-theory-for-physicists/21006#21006) but since it's not mentioned, I'll recommend it here too:

Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics by Michael Tinkham

Just read the introduction, and you'll get a sense of what to expect.  The mathematical development can be a bit tricky if you're not used to graduate level books but there are lots of physical explanations--before page 100.