# What is a good mathematical introduction to QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, mathematics

I've noticed that, any time I try to pick up Peskin and Schroeder, the main stumbling block it the leap in mathematical constructs from QM. Is there a good textbook that could teach me some of the math I need to know (advanced properties of Fourier transforms, vector integration tricks, etc.) to get a foothold on this?

I noticed this question might be misleading; I am not looking for a mathematical-physics take on QFT, anything regarding rigorous abstract algebra, topology, etc. Mainly I'm looking for what might be the textbook between the level of undergraduate and graduate math curriculum that contains principles used in introductory QFT.

Again, I am not trying to answer this question [Quantum Field Theory from a mathematical point of view](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27700/quantum-field-theory-from-a-mathematical-point-of-view). I am an engineer with a decent background in QM but I can't understand the math in QFT. I am not looking for a mathematical approach to QFT as I would be hopefully lost, I am looking for a source to give me the mathematical pre-requisites for QFT.

Comment: Comments to the edited version: the question is *still* a duplicate, in this case of [Mathematical Prerequisites for QFT](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135104/mathematical-prerequisites-for-qft?rq=1)