# Product of representations of Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

How represent angular momentum in representation $(a,b)\otimes (c,d)=(a\otimes c,b\otimes d)$ ?

I also post [Tensor product of representations of Lorentz group](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543618/)

Agreements: $I_a$ is $(2a+1)$-dimensional matrix, and $J_b=J^{(b)} $ (index $i$ is removed)

I try

$$(a,b)=I_a\otimes J_b +J_a\otimes I_b,$$ by definition.

$\pi_1\otimes \pi_2(X)=\pi_1(X)\otimes I_{dim(\pi_2)}+I_{dim(\pi_1)}\otimes \pi_2(X)$

then

$$(a,b)\otimes(c,d)(J)=J_{(a,b)}\otimes I_{(a,b)}+I_{(a,b)}\otimes J_{(c,d)}=$$
$$=(I_a\otimes J_b +J_a\otimes I_b)\otimes I_c\otimes I_d+I_a\otimes I_b\otimes (I_c\otimes J_d +J_c\otimes I_d)=$$
$$=J_a\otimes I_b\otimes I_c\otimes I_d+I_a\otimes J_b\otimes I_c\otimes I_d+I_a\otimes I_b\otimes J_c\otimes I_d+I_a\otimes I_b\otimes I_c\otimes J_d$$

but,

$$(a\otimes b,c\otimes b)=I_{a\cdot b}\otimes J_{c\cdot b}+...$$

where $I_{a\cdot b}$ is unit matrix with dimension $(2a+1)(2b+1)$, and $J_{c\cdot b}$ is representation of angular momentum operator in $(2c+1+2d+1)$ dimension.

And we have $J_{cd}\neq I_c\otimes J_d$

How ?

Comment: Your r.h.s. interpretation of your concluding "but," expression is not even wrong. "Addition of spins", the Kronecker product, entails multiplying, not adding, their dimensions. Try to summarize your undergraduate knowledge about them by "adding" three spins in plain angular momentum! Your correct coproduct should be linear in the three J_a 's and should *obey the angular momentum Lie Algebra*. Review how Lie Groups work. It should be all in your text.

Comment: Hint: try supplanting ⊗ for $\cdot$ in your unsound relation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sexl Urbantke]

I must change Kronecker product with matrix mul. product because relation 8.1.1. is true ?