# Where Does the Exponent Come From in the Expression for the Rotation Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

I am currently reading John S. Townsend's "A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics." In section 2.2 he introduces the $\hat J$ operator, which he refers to as "the generator of rotations." He gives the following equation, which expresses an infinitesimal rotation about the z-axis in terms of $\hat J$  :
$$\hat R(d\phi \boldsymbol{k})=1-{i \over \hbar}\hat J_zd\phi$$
He then goes on to explain that we can build any rotation needed by using an infinite number of these infinitesimal rotations. Thus:
$$d\phi=\lim_{N \to \infty}{\phi \over N} $$
Using these two expressions, he writes a third expression which is:
$$ \hat R(\phi \boldsymbol{k})=\lim_{N \to \infty}\big [1-{i \over \hbar}\hat J_z\big({\phi \over N}\big)\big ]^N$$
I understand everything except the $N$ in the exponent of the final expression. I've considered the idea that writing the $N$ in the expression is just a formalism. Because when the rotation operator is expressed as above it can also be written like this: $$\hat R(\phi \boldsymbol{k})=\exp\big [{-i\hat J_z\phi \over \hbar}\big]$$
The idea that it is simply formalism seems wrong to me, however, because if this were true why not just define $\hat R(d\phi\boldsymbol{k})$ differently in the original expression so that $N$ would appear as desired in the final expression? This leads me to believe there is some mathematical step I am missing.

What exactly is the source of $N$ in the exponent?

Comment: The power of $N$ is just applying the operator $\hat R(d\phi \boldsymbol{k})$ $N$ times.

Comment: I see now. Thank you. I was afraid it was something that simple.

Comment: Actually, it's not that simple. This book appears to avoid Lie groups and Lie algebras. Someday physics instructors will teach the basics of Lie theory as it pertains to rotation and thereby avoid the hokey, hand-waving "physics math" of "infinitesimal rotations". The mathematics of rotation made much more sense to me once I learned Lie theory. You don't need to go all the way to "mathy math" (where everything is so ridiculous abstract) to understand Lie theory, at least not the parts of Lie theory used within physics.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks for the insight. I may try to look into that. Do you have any suggestions of what I could read to understand Lie theory as it pertains to physics, without going into the "mathy math," as you say?

Comment: @wgrenard - This question, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/comprehensive-book-on-group-theory-for-physicists, has some good suggestions with regard to books. Some good freebies on the internet: http://people.physics.tamu.edu/pope/geom-group.pdf is aimed at group theory as it pertains to general relativity; http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg07.pdf is aimed at group theory as it pertains to quantum mechanics. https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Howe600-623.pdf claims to be very basic, but it devolves quickly into "mathy math".