# Textbook on group theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory

Can you recommend me a good textbook on group theory? I am interested in particular in tensor representation of a group, e.g. why $ 3 \otimes 3 = 6 \oplus \bar 3$ for $ \rm SU(3) $. Is there any textbook that can explain clearly that?

Comment: *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics* by Georgi definitely; also check out the lecture videos that are based on it at pirsa.org.

Comment: I think a similar question is somewhere asked and answered on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comprehensive book on group theory for physicists?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JamalS said, I would also suggest Georgi's book as #1 for your question. Also the one by S. Sternberg, Group Theory and Physics. If you want something more formal, check Fulton and Harris.