# Books about Group Theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I was looking for a book to complement the lecture notes of the course for a more intuitive approach to the subject and full of examples (mathematical), because the handouts seem only a bunch of mathematical definitions. I've read the suggested books in the question [Comprehensive book on group theory for physicists?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108), but that's not what I'm looking for. In fact, they either deal with a few subjects, or have too physical examples. I was looking for more geometric examples. The program of our course (the third year physics study) is this:

1. Groups and axioms:

Axioms of the group. Finished and infinite group. Examples. SN groups. Continuous and discreet group.

Abelian and non-Abelian group. Unchanged subgroups and subgroups.

Isomorphism and homomorphism between groups. Simple and semi-simple groups.

2. Lie groups and Lie algebra:

Lie groups and Lie algebra. Structure constant. Examples.

3. Representation theory:

Representation of the group. Irreducible representations. Schur's lemma. Characters.

4. Basic group / groups of homotopies:

Fundamental group and groups of general homotopies. Exact succession.

5. SU Group (2), SO (3) and SU (3):

Groups and algebra of SU (2), SO (3) and SU (3). Isospin. Spin and rotations in R3. Wigner-Eckart theorem.

Tableaux of Young

6. Representations of the SO group (4), of the Lorentz SO group (3.1)

and Poincaré: Group and algebra of SO (4). Vectors of Lenz and hydrogen atom. Lorentz Group.

7. Roots and weights; Dynkin diagrams:

Vectors of roots and weights. Dynkin diagrams and the classification of compact groups.