# A question about the equation $\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}=1\oplus0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, quantum-spin, representation-theory

I have a question about this equation: $$\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}=1\oplus0.$$

I'm a bit confused by the right-hand side. Should '1' and '0' be interpreted as the total spin? If so, if there're two particles both have spin $-\frac{1}{2}$, why there's no -1 on the right-hand side? Could '1' and '0' be treated like two orthogonal subspaces of the total Hilbert space? Also, why there's a 3 by 3 block corresponds to 1 and 1 by 1 block corresponds to 0? Thanks!!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534887/2451

Comment: Thanks!! I've seen that page but I'm still a bit confused with what each of the blocks on the right-hand side means.

Comment: Do you understand this is the tensor product of a pair of 2x2 matrices into a 4x4 matrix which reduces to a 3x3 matrix block (triplet)  and a singlet ("1") block?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I do understand the 4 by 4 matrix, but I'm not quite sure what the 3x3 matrix block means, and if '0' and '1' stands for the two spin systems, why there's no '-1' on the right-hand side (if two particles both spin down).

Comment: Hey Zhengrong, those numbers are the _maximal_ spin of each of the respective particles. For example when we say that the electron has spin 1/2, we really mean its MAXIMAL spin is 1/2. However the actual spin can take values of 1/2 or -1/2. It's just a way of naming things that is at times misleading. Not sure if that's your whole question though.. there is more to know on the meaning of that equation. If only we could just remove the circles on the plus signs, everything would be obvious! ;)

Comment: Thanks!! That helps:)

Comment: @doublefelix *If only we could just remove the circles on the plus signs, everything would be obvious!* No, it wouldn’t. It would become $\frac12\times\frac12=1+0$, which is nonsense. It would be obvious as arithmetic if we wrote it in terms the *dimensions* $2s+1$ of the representations, $2 \times 2=3+1$, instead of in terms of the quantum numbers $s$.

Comment: @Frobenius Thanks for the tip:)

Comment: Haha. Whoops. My humor was a fail. I'll leave my post up for the first, non-humor part of it. Yes, that's true, $0 \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the related question is not so much help to you because you have a much more fundamental misunderstanding. Once we clear that up, any further questions should be answered by the above.

There is no such $-1$ or $-1/2$ system.

For this we have to be clear on the difference between two different angular momentum quantum numbers, $\ell$ and $m$. They come from two different operators,
$$\begin{align}
\langle L^2\rangle &= \hbar^2 \ell (\ell + 1),\\
\langle L_z \rangle &= \hbar m,
\end{align}
$$for some arbitrary axis $z$ which we choose to co-diagonalize with $L^2$. Now there is an obvious relationship where if $|m| = \ell + 1$ then you would have $\langle L^2\rangle < \langle L_z^2\rangle$ which would be unphysical, so there is a clear restriction that $|m|\le 1$ must be maintained. Within that you have integer steps of $m$, so an $\ell = 1$ system allows $m = -1, 0, 1$ inside of that total-angular-momentum.

To the spin story we add that half-integers are allowed and if $\ell$ is a half-integer then $m$ is also a half-integer, so for an $\ell = \frac12$ system then $m = -\frac12, +\frac12.$

But the key thing is that you are describing the world in terms of $m$ but the equation that you are looking at describes the world in terms of $\ell.$ There are no spin-negative-one-half systems, there are just spin-one-half systems which happen to be most-pointed-along the negative $z$-axis for whatever $z$ we happened to use to diagonalize.

It is worth also re-emphasizing these words “most-pointed-along.” When we say that the spin is $-1/2$ we are saying that the total amount of the spin is a definite $\sqrt{3/4}~\hbar$ but that only $\hbar/2$ of it is pointed in the $-z$-direction. This is why if you follow up with an $x$-measurement, say, you see $+x$ with 50% probability and $-x$ with 50% probability, the vector is actually in some sense distributed along a “ring” $(L_x, L_y, L_z) = (\sqrt{1/2} \cos\theta, \sqrt{1/2} \sin\theta, -1/2)$ for $0 \le \theta < 2\pi.$

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! That's really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

This equation is an equation for representations of the Lie algebra of rotations. It is a fact proven in every quantum mechanics book that the irreducible representations of the angular momentum algebra $[J_i,J_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}J_k$ are spin $j$ systems where $j\in \mathbb{N}/2=\{0,1/2,1,3/2,2,\dots\}$. We thus call this representation by the integer $j$. Now, we can take tensor products and direct sum of representations. This is what the formula $1/2\otimes 1/2=0\oplus 1$ refers to. Physically, it says that a composite system consisting of two spin $1/2$ particles has states of total spin $0$ and states of total spin $1$. In particular, in this system the states corresponding to total spin $0$ and those of total spin $1$ are orthogonal. This is part of the definition of direct sum of unitary representations.

Now, note that a spin $j=1/2$ particle can have two states, one in which the spin is up and one in which the spin is down. The representation $j=1/2$ is spanned by these 2 states $m=1/2,-1/2$.

Finally, when people say that there is a 3 by 3 block corresponding to $1$ they are referring to the fact that the representation $1$ is three dimensional. It has states with $m=-1,0,1$. On the other hand, the representation $0$ is 1 dimensional. Its only state has $m=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It makes more sense to me now:)