# How can I relate group theory with 2 spin-1/2 electrons coupling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

I've learned some basic ideas of group theory like the basis for a group representation.

In 2 spin-1/2 electrons coupling case,
it is said $$2\otimes2=1\oplus3.$$

The direct product can be reduced to some direct sum. The basis belongs to one representation of a "group".

My question is, what is the concrete "group" here?
Is it "$\{S^2_{total }\}$"  alone?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Try to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your equations. It is as simple as enclosing equations using dollar signs `$`.

Comment: see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The group is the ${\rm SU}(2)$ of spin.

Comment: The angular momenta are the *generators* of the group elements, they are not themselves the group. The elements of the group are $U(\hat n, \phi)=e^{-i\phi\hat n \cdot \vec S}$

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/534887/what-does-this-notation-for-spin-mean-mathbf-frac-1-2-otimes-mathbf-frac-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, what is the concrete "group" here?
> Is it "$\{S^2_{total }\}$"  alone?

No, it is not $\{S^2_{total }\}$ alone, nor any combination of the angular momenta alone that form the group of interest. The group of interest is the rotation group.

The angular momenta (e.g., $S_x$, $S_y$, $S_z$) are the "generators" of the group.

We exponentiate the generators to get the group elements:
$$
U(\hat n, \theta) = e^{-i\theta \hat n\cdot \vec S}\;,
$$

---

For example, for rotations about the $z$ axis where $\hat n = \hat z$ we have:
$$
U(\hat z, \theta) = e^{-i\theta S_z}\;,
$$
which, for the 2x2 representation just looks like:
$$
e^{-i\theta S_z}=
\left(\begin{matrix}
e^{-i\theta/2} & 0 \\
0 & e^{+i\theta/2}
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

---

As a further example, consider the addition of two 2x2 $S_z$ angular momenta, which results in a 4x4 matrix representation:
$$
S_z^{(\text{total})} = S_z\otimes 1_2 + 1_2\otimes S_z
$$
$$
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
which can be transformed via a unitary transformation into:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
where now it is more clear that this matrix is the direct sum of a "spin 1" $S_z$ matrix:
$$
S_z^{\text{spin-$1$}}=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
which is non-trivial,
and a "spin 0" S_z matrix:
$$
S_z^{\text{spin-$0$}} = \left(\begin{matrix}0\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
where you can see why we call this latter "spin 0" representation "trivial." (It generates the trivial representation of the group where all members are represented by the number $1 = e^0$).

Here, we have only provided an example for z-angular momenta, which is fairly simple. However, the block diagonalization "works" for all the momentum components.

---

In general when we add two angular momenta, we can perform matrix manipulations to put the resulting direct product matrix into a direct sum form. This is what is meant by the notation:
$$
2\otimes 2 = 3\otimes 1\;,
$$
or equivalently, if stated in terms of spin values rather than matrix sizes:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes \frac{1}{2} = 1\oplus 0\;.
$$

As another example, in terms of spin not matrix size:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes 1 = \frac{3}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}\;,
$$
or, in terms of matrix size:
$$
2*3 = 4 + 2\;.
$$

For the example of $\frac{1}{2}\otimes 1$, after block diagonalizing the spin matrices, we find that the rotation matrices can be written in block diagonal form as well like:
$$
R^{\frac{3}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}} = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\left(
\begin{matrix}.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.
\end{matrix}
\right) & \vec 0 \\
\vec 0^T & \left(
\begin{matrix}
.&. \\
.&.
\end{matrix}
\right) 
\end{matrix}
\right)\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!