# What does it mean to 'combine' spin 1/2 particles

Tags: hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory, quantum-states

I'm trying to understand a phenomenon covered in several resources that I think I'm struggling with due to my lack of understanding of its meaning.

The idea is that 2 spin 1/2 particles can combine to form 4 spin states. These are broken down into the following prescriptions:

1. $$|1,1\rangle = |\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$$
2. $$|1,0\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}(|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle+|\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle)$$
3. $$|1,-1\rangle = |\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle$$
4. $$|0,0\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}(|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle-|\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle).$$

My understanding is that each of the $$|s,m\rangle$$ states refers to a particle. In this case, $s = 1/2$ and $m = 1/2$ or $-1/2$ referring to spin up or spin down respectively.

These individual states then form a system which has an overall spin of 1 or 0 and another quantity which I think is the projection of the spin onto the $z$-axis but I'm not really sure  as to the meaning/importance of this.

By this understanding, I read the above as you can get the first state as a combination of 2 spin up spin 1/2 particles and the third state as a combination of 2 spin down spin 1/2 particles.

I'm a little bit more confused by the others though. Is this 4 particles in the state or just a statement that it could be up/down or down/up with 50/50 odds. If so, what is the difference between these? Also, where does the root 1/2 come from? I assume some normalisation thing but can't see the exact reasoning.

Sorry, I appreciate that this is a big question. I just essentially want a breakdown of what $s$ and $m$ are, what the 4 statements physically represent and how the total state is derived from the individual states/vice versa.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/534887/what-does-this-notation-for-spin-mean-mathbf-frac-1-2-otimes-mathbf-frac-1).

Comment: I don't think the proposed duplicate is particularly helpful in answering the OP here.  It's certainly related, but it assumes a pretty high level of math background not needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

From the four independent tensor-product basis states:
$$|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$$
$$|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$$
$$|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$$
$$|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$$

You can form whatever different linear combination you would like.

However, *usually*, you would like to form linear combinations that make it easier to solve a problem. And *usually* the problem you would like to solve involves a Hamiltonian that is invariant under rotations, and thus commutes with the **total** angular momentum squared, and **total** z-angular momentum.

The four basis states written above do not transform simply under rotations. This is because they are not eigenfunctions of the **total** angular momentum squared ($\vec L^2 = (\vec L^{(1)}+\vec L^{(2)})^2$). Rather, they are eigenfunctions of the **individual** angular momenta squared (${L^{(1)}}^2$, ${L^{(2)}}^2$) and z-angular momenta ($L_z^{(1)}$, $L_z^{(2)}$).

This is why we like to form linear combinations that make up three new independent basis states:
$$
|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle
+|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle
\right)
$$
$$
|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle\;,
$$
which transform like a vector. This "vector" representation is also referred to as "triplet" or "spin $1$" or sometimes just "$1$".

And a linear combination of a fourth independent state:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle
-|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle
\right)
$$
which transforms like a scalar. This scalar combination is also referred to as "singlet" or "spin $0$" or sometimes just "$0$".

This can be written symbolically as:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2} = 1 \oplus 0
$$

---

Similarly, if we wanted to ["add"](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Quantum_Mechanics_(Fowler)/04%3A_Angular_Momentum_Spin_and_the_Hydrogen_Atom/4.07%3A_Adding_Angular_Momenta) three spin-$1/2$ angular momentum we would find:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}
=(1 \oplus 0)\otimes \frac{1}{2}
=\frac{3}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}
$$

Similarly, if we wanted to "add" four spin-$1/2$ angular momentum we would find:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}
=(1 \oplus 0)\otimes \frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}
=(\frac{3}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2})\otimes\frac{1}{2}
=2\oplus 1\oplus 1\oplus 0 \oplus 1 \oplus 0\;,
$$
and so on.

---

> Is this 4 particles in the state or just a statement that it could be up/down or down/up with 50/50 odds.

In the case you are asking about, there are only ever two particles.

> If so, what is the difference between these?

The difference is how they transform under rotations.

> Also, where does the root 1/2 come from?

It comes from normalizing the state.