# Working out the properties of the Special Unitary Lie algebra $su(n)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, lie-algebra, linear-algebra

Given the special unitary group, we can define

$$ M = -iX = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & -ia_{12}+b_{12} & ... & -a_{1n} + b_{1n} \\
ia_{12}+b_{12} & b_{22} & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
ia_{1n}+b_{1n} & ... & ... & b_nn = -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} b_{kk}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where all elements $a,b$ are Real.

How would one find the dimension of $su(n)$ from this? I know the answer is supposed to be $n^2 -1$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Also, one can show that the Pauli and Gen-Mann matrices span $su(2)$ and $su(3)$ respectively. How can we generalize this to an arbitrary n to find a set of basis martrices that are orthogonal under the inner product?

Also, what are the normalizations required to ensure that: $2tr(t^at^b) = \delta^{ab}$?

Comment: Review [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices). What does your text detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many questions for one post. I'll answer the first and the last since the second is a little bit involved and you can find the solution looking to the book Lie Algebras in particle physics by *Georgi*.

Take the $SU(N)$ Lie algebra. Being a complex Lie group you'll need at least $2N^2$ parameters, $N^2$ for the real part and $N^2$ for the imaginary. If you see your matrix $U$ in  in $SU(N)$ on the diagonal you have no imaginary part, so $N$ parameters go away. Moreover the imaginary part is antisymmetric and so half of the parameters are fixed: not counting the diagonal there are $$\frac{N^2-N}{2}$$ fixed imaginary parameters. For the real ones they are symmetric and so another $\frac{N^2-N}{2}$ fixed parameters. What remains is the last diagonal element which is fixed by all the others and so another $1$ fixed parameters.

The number of free parameters is then $$2N^2-\frac{N^2-N}{2}-\frac{N^2-N}{2}-N-1 = 2N^2 - N^2 + N-N-1 = N^2-1$$

The normalisation stays the same $$\text{Tr } t^a t^b = \frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}$$

Comment: (Georgi is a terrible text...  see the suggestions here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/36194 )

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ahah that's not the first time you say this to me! But yeah, I'm sure there are better text, I remember having lot's of difficulties understanding it and still now it's not all so clear. But since it was the text with which I was introduced to this topics is what I can recommend!

Comment: It’s a bit of a pity: Georgi did a lot of great things (and his textbook in a sense was quite influential) but this is not his best contribution.