# Book on Representations and Group Theory in Particle Physics for Mathematicians

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, group-theory, representation-theory

Is there a book for someone who *already* knows some group theory and theory of group representations on the mathematical side, and just wants something which explains the applications in particle physics and the Standard Model?

To be clear, I am not looking for a book which is intended or written for physicists, and I do not need anything extremely rigorous.  I simply need a book which explains how things work with groups and group reps in particle physics and the Standard Model from the physical point of view

Comment: How about this one:  https://www.amazon.com/Lie-Groups-Algebras-Physicists/dp/9814616907

Comment: I suspect you want to go to the [mother load question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/comprehensive-book-on-group-theory-for-physicists). "For mathematicians" in the title suggests rigor, but you are after the opposite?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Tom: what kind of mathematical rep theory do you know? Unless you know unitary representation theory for noncompact groups like SO(p,q), your math knowledge might not give you much advantage and thus the question might be moot.

Comment: @Tom: A. O. Barut and R. Raczka "Theory of Group Representations and applications" is probably the best choice for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good reference is a book by [https://www.amazon.com/Symmetries-Lie-Algebras-Represen-Mathematical/dp/0521541190](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521541190) - it is a about group theory and application in Physics, but aimed more at mathematicians.

I would also recommend [https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521558859](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521558859) as a something more applied and physicist aimed, with applications in crystallography and condensed matter.

And the book by Wu-Ki Tung, has a detailed discussion in applications to QFT and symmetry of classical and qunatum systems.
[https://www.amazon.com/Group-Theory-Physics-Wu-Ki-Tung/dp/9971966565/ref=pd_sbs_14_2/134-6903610-5306660?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=9971966565&pd_rd_r=cbb5053e-51fb-4c15-b965-836f7f44823d&pd_rd_w=K52lx&pd_rd_wg=nd473&pf_rd_p=b65ee94e-1282-43fc-a8b1-8bf931f6dfab&pf_rd_r=1CQDXH2D1AXRVF8Z53KC&psc=1&refRID=1CQDXH2D1AXRVF8Z53KC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9971966565)