# Good introductory book about Group Theory?

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, education

I am looking for a good introductory book about Group Theory for physicists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comprehensive book on group theory for physicists?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/)

Comment: Which part of the group theory is you major interetsed: finite group ( for chemistry, crystal), or infinite group (for quantum mechanics)?

Comment: Try the Zee book mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Thank you for the Zee book! I am interested in quantum mechanics.