# Book recommendation on group theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, group-theory, lie-algebra

Currently I am learning Quantum field theory, however I notice the lack of group theory knowledge especially Lie Algebra is quite fatal to my understanding. I hope to find some materials that can self study this field. My field of interest is mainly on quantum field theory and related theoretical particle physics.

My mathematical skill is on the level of standard beginning postgraduate students on physics, I learn mathematical methods from physics side instead of mathematics side, so I am not familiar with the style of Definition proves lemma corollary. I hope the material focus more on the application on physics theory.

Please recommend some lecture/course materials/books that may meet these requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comprehensive book on group theory for physicists?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/)

Comment: Brian Hall's book on Lie Groups, Algebras and Representation Theory is a good read. As you say if you are learning QFT you will absolutely need to know about Lie groups and Lie algebras on top of standard group theory and it won't hurt to cover the representation theory of the Lorentz group (or $SL(2;\Bbb C)$).

Comment: Thanks! It seems a good book suits my interest