# Group Theory Book

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, representation-theory, education

I am looking for a **problem-and-solutions** book that deals with group theory topics that are important in physics. Some topics I am looking for are as follows.

(1) Group Representations

(2) Representations of the Symmetry group

(3) Continuous groups

(4) Lorentz and Poincare groups

Comment: Try the exercises in Wu Ki Tungs book, even if there is no solution manual.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the book *Group Theory in Physics - Problems and Solutions* by Michael Aivazis. Here is the table of contents.

(1) Basic group theory

(2) Group Representations

(3) General properties of Irreducible Vectors and Operators

(4) Representations of the Symmetry group

(5) 1 - D Continuous groups

(6) SO(3)

(7) SU(2) and SO(3)

(8) Euclidean groups

(9) Lorentz and Poincare groups

(10) Space Inversion

(11) Time Reversal

(12) Finite dimensional representations of the classical group