# What is the action of generators on operators?

Tags: operators, group-theory, lie-algebra

I have been following "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics: From Isospin to Unified Theories". In the textbook, the chapter on tensor operators defines them as operators that transform under commutation with generators as
$[J_a, O^s_l] = O^s_m[J^s_a]_{ml}$, where $J_a$ are the generators, and $O^s_l$ is the tensor operator. My question is, where does this definition come from?

Sidenote: Any other recommendations for textbooks covering similar topics would be highly appreciated. I am finding this set of notes a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: Tensor operators are covered in many graduate-level QM books, such as Sakurai. This definition means that $O_l^s$ transforms as spin-s under SO(3).

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/comprehensive-book-on-group-theory-for-physicists).