# Weights and roots of $SU(3)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I am self-studying group theory from *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics* by H. Georgi and I am having trouble following some of his arguments. In section 7.2 titled *Weights and roots of $SU(3)$* he starts out by finding the weights of the generators
\begin{equation}
T_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\hspace{1cm}
T_{8} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The eigenvectors and the associated weights are given to be
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
& \longrightarrow (1/2,\sqrt{3}/6)\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}
&\longrightarrow (-1/2,\sqrt{3}/6)\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}
&\longrightarrow (0,-\sqrt{3}/3)
\end{align}
So far so good. What I don't understand is how Georgi finds the roots. He says that "The roots are going to be differences of weights, because the corresponding generators take us from one weight to another." I do not understand this statement, can someone please elaborate?

Next he says "It is not hard to see that the corresponding generators are those that have only one off-diagonal entry"
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T_1\pm i T_2) &= E_{\pm 1,0}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T_4\pm i T_5) &= E_{\pm 1/2,\pm\sqrt{3}/2}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T_6\pm i T_7) &= E_{\mp 1/2,\pm\sqrt{3}/2}
\end{align}
I thought the generators were the $T_i$'s. Can someone please explain? I find the book to be a bit terse sometimes and lacking elaborate explanations.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the normalization of $T_8$

Comment: @lcv thanks, edited.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Standard_basis) might illuminate the picture for you. Presumably you have mastered [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system).

Comment: One should never use Georgi to learn this topic. See [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/36194) for alternatives.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks. I feel like the book is so condensed that it serves better as a refresher.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the non-zero roots are the ladder operators of the algebra.  The zero roots (at the center of the root diagram) are the diagonal operators.

Now, whether you use $T_1$ or $T_1\pm i T_2$ depends on how you define $T_1$ and $T_2$.  In this case, it seems they are defined as hermitian so, like $L_x$ and $L_y$, it is the combinations $L_\pm = L_x\pm i L_y$ that are the ladder operators. Their matrix representation (as $2\times 2$ matrices acting on a 2d Hilbert space) contains zeroes everywhere except for a single $1$ somewhere off-diagonal.

In general, the ladder operators satisfy $[h_i,T_\alpha]=\alpha(i) T_\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a root and $\alpha(i)$ is a component of the root vector.  This simply generalizes $[L_z,L_\pm]=\pm L_\pm$.  The normalization of the diagonal operators is usually chosen so the roots span a regular lattice in $\mathbb{R}^r$, where $r$ is the rank of the algebra.  Moreover, the weights of a representation, when placed on the lattice, all differ by an integer linear combination of roots.

Thus, just like $L_\pm$ move you between $su(2)$ states $\vert \ell,m\rangle$ of different weights, the non-zero roots will move you between states of different weights.  It is almost tautological to see that applying various roots to a state of a given weight will produce a state with a weight that is exactly the linear combination related to the application of the roots: in other words, if
$$
E_\alpha E_\beta \vert \boldsymbol{m}\rangle
$$
then the resulting state will have weight $\boldsymbol{m}+\alpha+\beta$.

It must follow that $E_\beta\vert\boldsymbol{m}\rangle$ has weight $\boldsymbol{m}+\beta$ because
\begin{align}
h_iE_\beta\vert\boldsymbol{m}\rangle&= [h_i,E_\beta]\vert\boldsymbol{m}\rangle + E_\beta\,h_i\vert \boldsymbol{m}\rangle\\
&=\beta(i)E_\beta\vert\boldsymbol{m}\rangle+ m_i E_\beta\vert\boldsymbol{m}\rangle\, ,\\
&= (\beta(i)+m_i)\vert\boldsymbol{m}\rangle
\end{align}
or, in other words, $E_\beta\vert\boldsymbol{m}\rangle$ has weight component $m_i+\beta_i$ as it is an eigenstate of $h_i$ with this eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you so much @ZeroTheHero . It is much clearer to me now.